# Auto multiple animation rotate with continuously from slow rotate till to fastest rotate in the css at once call on/off onclick of an element?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, autorotate

This is more detailed description from the thread of what I've made on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61220874/multiple-animation-rotate-in-css-at-once-call-in-toggle-onclick-of-one-element). I have 3 animations on css what I've made in fiddle that are "animate1 (as a slow rotate), animate2 (as a medium rotate) and animate3 (as a fastest rotate)" with continuously repeated automatically not with rapided them onclick which is want to running at once call by toggle on/off of an onClick on an Element of "`<h1>`". During till now what I'd know from what my achievements has reached is just only for running them leading till to animate2 only. After that I don't know how to figured out an of this all ? Please anyone to take and help for solve this case and sorry about my worse english ...

[https://jsfiddle.net/bxeg3j2f](https://jsfiddle.net/bxeg3j2f/)
Fiddel's demo greates an achievements with the correct schedule of animations times of delay.

https://jsfiddle.net/cwp1hz34/2/
Fiddel's demo greates an achievements with the correct position of multi-animations places supposed be.

Comment: Post the code here as a [mcve]. BTW *"...not with rapided them onclick "* whuh?

Comment: @zer00ne hehe ...  I'm so so sory because of my lack. If you don't mind whould you correction me how supposed be I write there ?  to increassing of my english learning . cheers ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure about what you want. Just trying to guess it...

```css
.test {
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    animation: rotate linear 6s infinite;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {transform: rotate(0deg)}
  33% {transform: rotate(360deg)}
  66% {transform: rotate(1080deg)}
  100% {transform: rotate(7200deg)}

}


Another possible approach, making the speed increase smoother:
```

```html
<div class="test">A</div>
```

```css
.test {
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: block;
    width: 35px;
    padding: 0px 14px;
    animation: rotate 6s infinite;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.59,.07,.88,.64);
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {transform: rotate(0deg)}
  100% {transform: rotate(1800deg)}
}
```

```html
<div class="test">A</div>
```

Comment: Yeah. you did it. You are really understood what I want thanks @vals very very thank you.  But is we still can't combine that 3 animations become as one what I mean tobe concern here till today right ?

Comment: Happy that it helped you. But now, I don't understand your comment. This is one animation, not three. You want that the increase in speed is smoother ?

Comment: yes vals you are right in this case your solution is greate and more simply then mine which is very very complex and take so long lines too much. But in my any case  I have other any situation which is three animation must be combine become as one ...